# How to change the Tooltip position based on available space

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How do I make the tooltip appear on top if there's not enough space at the bottom, and vice-versa? Is there any CSS hack or I have to calculate it using JS?

```css
.foo {
  position: relative;
}

.tooltip {
  display: none;
}

.foo a:focus+.tooltip {
  display: block;
  background: black;
  position: absolute;
  color: white;
  padding: 5px;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="foo"><a href="#" class="foo"> this is a link</a>
  <div class="tooltip">this is a tooltip</div>
</div>
<div class="foo"><a href="#" class="link">this is a link</a>
  <div class="tooltip">this is a tooltip</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

**You must use js to calculate position of your element on page. in dynamic page your element will apperar in top, bottom, left ,right.**

If link is present in 1st half of screen then add `.tooltipTop` else add `.tooltipBottom` class.

You can test by adding multiple link in code.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Side Project</title>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito+Sans" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<style>
body{
 height:auto;
}

.foo {  position: relative;}

.tooltip {
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  background: black;
  color: white;
  padding: 5px;
  z-index: 1;
}

.tooltipTop{
  top: 20px;
  display: block;
}

.tooltipBottom{
 top: -25px;
 display: block;
}
</style>
<body>
<div class="foo"><a href="#" class="link"> this is a link1</a>
  <div class="tooltip">this is a tooltip1</div>
</div>
<br>
<br>

<div class="foo"><a href="#" class="link">this is a link2</a>
  <div class="tooltip">this is a tooltip2</div>
</div> 

<div class="foo"><a href="#" class="link"> this is a link3</a>
  <div class="tooltip">this is a tooltip3</div>
</div>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<div class="foo"><a href="#" class="link">this is a link4</a>
  <div class="tooltip">this is a tooltip4</div>
</div> 
</body>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".foo").click(function(){
                var bodyheight = $("body").height();
  var halfbodyheight = bodyheight/2;
  
  var parent = $(this).parent();
  var position = $(this).position().top;

  if(position >= halfbodyheight){
   $(".tooltip").removeClass("tooltipBottom tooltipTop");
   $(this).find('.tooltip').addClass("tooltipBottom");
  }
  else{
   $(".tooltip").removeClass("tooltipBottom tooltipTop");
   $(this).find('.tooltip').addClass("tooltipTop");
  }
  
    });
});
</script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

well you can try this. It may help you.

CSS

```
.foo {
  position: relative;
}

.tooltip {
  display: none;
}

.foo a:focus+.tooltip {
  display: block;
  background: black;
  position: absolute;
  color: white;
  padding: 5px;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

Javascript

```
$("#tt").css({ top: $("#ll").position().top - 30 });
```

HTML

```
<br>
<br>
<div class="foo"><a href="#" class="foo" id="ll"> this is a link</a>
  <div class="tooltip" id="tt">this is a tooltip</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you can not it through CSS dynamically. You can always create a class and add it manually to the elements at bottom. But if you want a dynamic behavior, you need help of JS to determine space availability.

Answer (score 0):

You can  use bootstrap tooltip. If not below code can be helpful.

```css
.foo {
  position: relative;
}

.tooltip {
  display: none;
}

.foo a:focus+.tooltip {
  display: block;
  background: black;
  position: absolute;
  color: white;
  padding: 5px;
  z-index: 1;
}

.foo a:focus+.tooltip.top {
     top: -1.5em;
  }

  .foo a:focus+.tooltip.bottom {
    top: 1em;
  }
```

```html
<div class="foo"><a href="#" class="foo"> this is a link</a>
  <div class="tooltip top">this is a tooltip</div>
</div>
<div class="foo"><a href="#" class="link">this is a link</a>
  <div class="tooltip bottom">this is a tooltip</div>
</div>
```